torch.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory - Training Donut Model with Geforce RTX 3060 GPU
I am trying to train a hugging face model locally with my GPU which has 12 GB of memory.
Every time I run the code:
# Fine-tune the model
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    fp16=True,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    save_strategy="epoch",
    save_total_limit=1,
    predict_with_generate=True,
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=default_data_collator,
    train_dataset=dataset["train"],
)

trainer.train()

I am running into this error:
torch.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 526.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 12.00 GiB of which 0 bytes is free. Of the allocated memory 25.31 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 570.47 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management  (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#environment-variables)

I have already set PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLIOC_CONF, updated my drivers (said I have CUDA 12.6), closed every other program, and restarted my computer counteless times.
My pytorch version is 2.5.1+cu124
my nvidia-smi output is:
Sun Dec  8 19:45:01 2024
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 566.36                 Driver Version: 566.36         CUDA Version: 12.7     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Driver-Model | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060      WDDM  |   00000000:07:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   52C    P0             41W /  170W |    1123MiB /  12288MiB |      6%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      5500    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                     N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7024    C+G   ...oogle\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7476    C+G   ...siveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8416    C+G   ....0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\HxOutlook.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8452    C+G   ...on\131.0.2903.86\msedgewebview2.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11068    C+G   ...2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11636    C+G   ...CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TextInputHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11972    C+G   ...tionsPlus\logioptionsplus_agent.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12388    C+G   ...n\NVIDIA app\CEF\NVIDIA Overlay.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13288    C+G   ...nt.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14980    C+G   ...oogle\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     16004    C+G   ...n\NVIDIA app\CEF\NVIDIA Overlay.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     16264    C+G   ...US\ArmouryDevice\asus_framework.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17228    C+G   ...mpt_builder\LogiAiPromptBuilder.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17420    C+G   ...ekyb3d8bbwe\PhoneExperienceHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17612    C+G   ...t.LockApp_cw5n1h2txyewy\LockApp.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     19580    C+G   ...__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     23468    C+G   ...Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     24116    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe      N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

